# how do I get the twitter users screen_name from tmhOAuth 0.7.5 after they authorize my app?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I use  tmhOAuth 0.7.5 to authorize andmy app and send tweets on behalf of my users and it works well so far but now I want to add a little piece - I want to grab the users screen_name (ultimately I want their twitter url eg https://twitter.com/screen_name for links).  I'd rather not upgrade my version of tmhOAuth  right now just for fear doing so might break some of my code and I'm pressed for time today.  So the question is :
  how do I get the twitter users screen_name from tmhOAuth 0.7.5 after they authorize my app?

I tried examining the $tmhOAuth object but it does not contain the info I want.

PS: ok, tried the newest version 0.8.2 and it didn't seem to break anything so far and just added this part after authorization to get the name :

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->user_request(array(
  'url' => $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/account/verify_credentials')
));

if ($code == 200)  
$data = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);
$name = $fdata['screen_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'fdata' a typo? Changing the code to the following seems to work fine for me:

```
if ($code == 200) { 
    $data = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);
    $name = $data['screen_name'];
}
```